# my_sql query group by

Tags: php, sql

I have a table in my mysql db that has two columns: group and subgroup. See below.

```
 group, tGroup 
 grp-A, sub-B  
 grp-B, sub-A  
 grp-A, sub-B      
 grp-B, sub-A  
 grp-B, sub-C  
 grp-C, sub-B
```

What I am trying to get is the number of record for each unique couple group/subGroup. See here below the result I excpect:

```
group, tGroup, count
grp-A, sub-B,   4      
grp-C, sub-B,   2
```

After reading some posts I tried several sql queries using group by, count(), but I do not manage to get the excpected result. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: wat.. this is a totaly different question than which i clicked on from the "top questions" page..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp